# How to wait for a TableView's initialization in TornadoFX (JavaFX)?

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I'm working with a JavaFX `TableView` and I noticed that if I load a lot of data into the table some time passes while it is actually visible after I create an instance of it.

My problem is that I want to access a `ScrollBar` of this table but I can only look it up after the initialization of the table is complete so I have this code currently:

```
    runAsync {
        val start = System.nanoTime()
        var bar = fetchHorizontalScrollbar()
        while(bar.isEmpty() && System.nanoTime() - start < 10L * 1000 * 1000 * 1000) {
            bar = fetchHorizontalScrollbar()
        }
        bar
    }.ui { bar ->
        // do stuff with the scrollbar
    }
```

Is there a way to listen to this initialization instead of busy waiting for the `ScrollBar` to appear?

Comment: Can you show me how you put data into the TableView?